# PageMethods slows the process and working descending

Tags: javascript, pagemethods

I have many pagemethods on my page. Each methods are used for fetching data from the database. I have ordered them in the following way. but my problem is the lines outside the success methods but inside the main function are working before the pagemethods complete the process

```
function check_valid()
{
     // some code
     Pagemethod1
     function suc1()
     {
       //some code
       PageMethod2
       function suc2()
       {
         //some code
         Page Method3
         function suc3()
         {
           //some code
         }
         function err3(){}
       }
       function err2(){}
     }
     function err1(){}
 return true;               //this line is working before the pagemethods complete the process
 }
```

Comment: Page methods are `AJAX` calls, and ajax gets executed async, which means that the javascript won't wait for the response from the server. This is why you need to pass a callback function and execute it when the ajax call completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
function check_valid()
{
     // some code
     Pagemethod1
     function suc1()
     {
       //some code
       PageMethod2
       function suc2()
       {
         //some code
         Page Method3
         function suc3()
         {
           //some code
           return true;
         }
         function err3(){}
        }
       function err2(){}
     }
     function err1(){}
   }
```

Because PageMethods will work one by one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with "PageMethods" but it sounds like each of these functions is asynchronous as it is receiving data from a remote database. Because JavaScript operates within one single thread, asynchronous processes usually have an option to attach a callback function that fires once the process is complete.  This allows javascript to do other things such as `return true` while its waiting for your slow database call, explaining your observation.

Instead, use a callback pattern with your database API:

```
editDatabase(args*, function() {
    //Stuff to do database call is complete
});
```

Alternatively, your database API might use an event pattern:

```
var myDb = new DB();
myDb.edit(args*)
myDb.bind('complete', function() {
    //Stuff to do database call is complete
});
```

Or, your database API might use promises, which you can read about [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

These patterns may take some getting used to if you are moving from a synchronous language, but they are essential to JavaScript.  You can also find a good guide to the asynchronous aspects of JavaScript [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027).

Answer (score 0):

Using a javascript class may help. Also callbacks are key for ajax.

```
function check_valid(){ 
 var fn = this; //assign this to a variable for ease of use
 var callbacks = []; //array to store all results
 var calls = []; //all ajax calls
 this.complete = function(callback){
  function check(){
   if(callbacks.length==calls.length){
    callback(callbacks);
   }else{
    setTimeout(function(){
     fn.check()
    },50);
   }
  }
  return fn;
 }
 this.callServ(params){
  calls.push(params);
  params.success = function(ret){
   callbacks.push({data:ret,status:'success'});
  }
  params.error = function(ret){
   callbacks.push({data:ret,status:'success'});
  }
  $.ajax(params);
  return fn;
 }
 return this;
}
```

This should allow you to do multiple calls systematically and then use a single callback to handle them all. I use jquery ajax to make the ajax call easier, and pass its same parameters.

So it would look like this to use:

```
var checkValid = new check_valid();

checkValid.callServ({url:url,data:data});
checkValid.callServ({url:url,data:data});
checkValid.callServ({url:url,data:data});

checkValid.complete(function(data){
 //data is an array of all call serv returns.
});
```

This may be far from what you currently have, the amount of information does not tell me enough of what exactly is being done. This example may be a little advanced, but it can give the illusion of being synchronous, at least as close as javascript can get.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own solution. After a long research i have come to the solution. that is pagemethods will be slow only because of their arrangement. We have to decide where to call it  and after which we have to call. Since I have reordered them, it gave some fault. Now its working good.